# SAS -- Find Sort Rank in Data Step

Tags: sas

I'm working with some SAS data, and am trying to figure out how to find a record's sort position in a datastep while using as few steps as possible.
Here's an example --

```
data Places;
   infile datalines delimiter=',';
   input state $ city $40. ;
   datalines;
WA,Seattle
OR,Portland
OR,Salem
OR,Tillamook
WA,Vancouver
;

Proc Sort data=WORK.PLACES;
    by STATE CITY;
run;

data WORK.PLACES;
    set WORK.PLACES;
    by STATE CITY;
    ST_CITY_RNK = _N_;
run;

Proc Sort data=WORK.PLACES;
    by CITY;
run;

data WORK.PLACES;
    set WORK.PLACES;
    by CITY;
    CITY_RNK = _N_;
run;
```

In this example, is there a way to calculate ST_CITY_RNK and CITY_RNK without sorting multiple times?  It feels like this should be possible with ordered hash tables, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, here's a hash approach:

```
data Places;
   infile datalines delimiter=',';
   input state $ city $40. ;
   datalines;
WA,Seattle
OR,Portland
OR,Salem
OR,Tillamook
WA,Vancouver
;
run;

data places;
    set places;
    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        declare hash h1(ordered:'a',dataset:'places');
        rc = h1.definekey('city');
        rc = h1.definedata('city');
        rc = h1.definedone();
        declare hiter hi1('h1');
        declare hash h2(ordered:'a',dataset:'places');
        rc = h2.definekey('state','city');
        rc = h2.definedata('state','city');
        rc = h2.definedone();
        declare hiter hi2('h2');
    end;
    t_city = city;
    t_state = state;
    rc = hi1.first();
    do city_rank = 1 by 1 until(t_city = city);
        rc = hi1.next();
    end;
    rc = hi2.first();
    do state_city_rank = 1 by 1 until(t_city = city and t_state = state);
        rc = hi2.next();
    end;
    state = t_state;
    city = t_city;
    drop t_:;
run;
```

Comment: Honestly, I expect you'll find that performance of this is seldom going to be any better than your original solution, and it might actually be worse for really large datasets. A better approach would be to replicate your logic directly - I might have a go later.

Answer (score 1):

Hash table would be doable.  Temporary arrays would have roughly the same effect and might be a bit easier.

The major limitation of either is what do you do with non-unique city names?  Salem, Oregon and Salem, Massachusetts?  Obviously in state-city rank that's fine, though you may find states with more than one Lincoln or similar, who knows; but in just City you'll certainly find several Columbias, Lincolns, Charlestons, etc.  My solution gives the same sort rank to all of them (but would then skip forward 6 or whatever to the next one).  The data step solution you post above would give them unique ranks.  The hash iterator could probably do either one.  You could tweak this with some effort to give unique ranks, but it would be work.

```
data Places;
   infile datalines delimiter=',';
   input state $ city $40. ;
   datalines;
WA,Seattle
OR,Portland
OR,Salem
OR,Tillamook
WA,Vancouver
;
run;

data sortrank;

    *Init pair of arrays - the one that stores the original values, and one to mangle by sorting;
  array states[32767] $ _temporary_;
  array states_cities_sorted[32767] $40. _temporary_ (32767*'ZZZZZ');
  array cities[32767] $40. _temporary_;
  array cities_sorted[32767] $40. _temporary_ (32767*'ZZZZZ');


    *Iterate over the dataset, load into arrays;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (Eof);
    set places end=eof;
    states[_n_] = state;;
    states_cities_sorted[_n_] = catx(',',state,city);
    cities[_n_] = city;
    cities_sorted[_n_] = city;
  end;

    *Sort the to-be-sorted arrays;
  call sortc(of states_cities_sorted[*]);
  call sortc(of cities_sorted[*]);


  do _i = 1 to _n_;
        *For each array element, look up the rank using `whichc`, looking for the value of the unsorted element in the sorted list;
    city_rank = whichc(cities[_i],of cities_sorted[*]);
    state_cities_rank = whichc(catx(',',states[_i],cities[_i]),of states_cities_sorted[*]);
        *And put the array elements back in their proper variables;
    city = cities[_i];
    state= states[_i];
        *And finally make a row output;
    output;
  end;

run;
```